# Retrieving the last record from MySql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the latest entry from multiples tables where i would like to get the last record inserted in to the database

This is my query

```
select distinct concat(e.firstname,' ',e.middleinitial,' ',e.lastname)
as empname, e.empid,egw.payperiodnumber,egw.payrollyear,date_format(cpd.paymentdate,'%m-%d-%Y')
as PaymentDate
from tblemployee e,tblemployeegrosswagesn egw,tblcustomerpaymentdates cpd
where e.empid=egw.empid and e.fedtaxid=egw.fedtaxid and egw.fedtaxid=cpd.fedtaxid
and e.PayFrequencyTypeID=cpd.payfrequencytype and 
cpd.payfrequencytype='MN' and 
cpd.payperiodnumber=egw.payperiodnumber and e.fedtaxid='546548321'
and (egw.empid,egw.payperiodnumber,egw.payrollyear) in (select empid,
payperiodid,payyear from tblcurpayresults where fedtaxid='546548321' order by empid) order by 
empid,payperiodnumber asc
```

I am getting the following result

[image]

Expected result is as follows

```
 Empname                   EmpID Payperiodno   Payrollyear   PaymentDate
Dorababu ldkfjg dlsfkgjwl   1430    1            2011        01-31-2012
Dorababu ldkfjg dlsfkgjwl   1430    2            2011        02-29-2012
Dorababu ldkfjg dlsfkgjwl   1430    3            2011        03-31-2012
Dorababu ldkfjg dlsfkgjwl   1430    4            2011        04-30-2012
Dorababu ldkfjg dlsfkgjwl   1430    5            2011        05-31-2012
Dorababu ldkfjg dlsfkgjwl   1430    6            2011        06-30-2012
```

Can any one help me please

Comment: not very clear question. ORDER BY?

Comment: May i know whats not clear to you. I would like to get the latest inserted record among the available

Comment: if you don't have an "inserted_date" column, it will be hard to do so. the sql code is a little bit messy.

Comment: You are effectively doing a JOIN query - which column of which table do you wish to sort on? ORDER BY `tbl.column` DESC

Answer (score 0):

Why does ORDER BY cpd.paymentdate not work?
Another way is to have a supplementary column in every table, something like "Created", which would be a UNIX timestamp.

Of course, you would have to write in a current timestamp upon every insert. Have a read here: http://www.keithjbrown.co.uk/vworks/mysql/mysql_p9.php

Comment: Why not add it in? MySQL does not automatically keep track of when you insert records into the table, not to the best of my knowledge anyway

Comment: If i add now i would like to add in the whole tables i am having

Answer (score 0):

Code reworked:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    CONCAT(e.firstname, ' ', e.middleinitial, ' ', e.lastname) AS empname, 
    e.empid,
    egw.payperiodnumber,
    egw.payrollyear,
    DATE_FORMAT(cpd.paymentdate, '%m-%d-%Y') as PaymentDate
FROM 
    tblemployee e,
    tblemployeegrosswagesn egw,
    tblcustomerpaymentdates cpd
WHERE 
    e.empid=egw.empid 
AND e.fedtaxid=egw.fedtaxid 
AND egw.fedtaxid=cpd.fedtaxid
AND e.PayFrequencyTypeID=cpd.payfrequencytype 
AND cpd.payfrequencytype='MN' 
AND cpd.payperiodnumber=egw.payperiodnumber 
AND e.fedtaxid='546548321'
AND (egw.empid,egw.payperiodnumber,egw.payrollyear) IN 
(
    SELECT 
        empid, 
        payperiodid, 
        payyear 
    FROM 
        tblcurpayresults 
    WHERE 
        fedtaxid='546548321' 
    ORDER BY 
        empid
) 
ORDER BY 
    empid, payperiodnumber ASC;
```

Is the first `ORDER BY` required?

If you add a TIMESTAMP column, it will automatically be updated with the current date/time when the row is inserted or updated. And you can ORDER BY that column.

EDIT: Also you may have the information_schema.tables table which has a column that stores each table update time. You can query this table, but I think it only works for myISAM tables.

Comment: yes but it helps other people to better understand your query.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using left joins to clarify your code and maybe some indentation/general formatting.

Also your data looks a little strange. Why would Payperiodno 1 = PaymentDate 07-31-2011 but Payperiodno 4 = PaymentDate 04-30-2012?

By looks of things the payperiodno is tax month and thus to my assumption of your data, payperiodno 4 should = paymentdate 30-10-2011 and remain consecutive and not jump from month 9 to month 4.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont wish to have a timestamp you could use an identity columt (surrogate key) with auto_increment then doing a search on max SK_### but without anything distinctively symbolising the insert order/time you will struggle.

Marcus Culver